# What can I do for an image to appear during the entire GIF animation?

Tags: gimp

Quiero poner una imagen estática sobre un gif usando gimp pero cuando le doy guardar solo muestra la imagen al final del gif.

`I want to put a static image over a gif using gimp but when I give it save it only shows the image at the end of the gif.`

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an animation where the static image is part of every frame, which, in Gimp parlance, means to replicate/merge your static image over every layer.

If you have more than a few frames there are scripts to help you do this, such as [`ofn-interleave-layers`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-tools/files/scripts/) (use `single layer over stack (title)`).

Make sure that you are not working on an optimized image, run `Filters > Animation > Unoptimize` before everything else. Once done, you can re-optimize the result (`Filters > Animation > Optimize (for GIF)`).